# is there a better way of assigning values to a matrix

Tags: matlab

say i have a matrix

```
A=zeros(10,3);
```

and a vector

```
ll=[1 1 1  2 2 2 3 1 3 2]';
```

and i want to assign the value in each row corresponding to  the value in ll for that row to be 1

i.e output would be

```
A= 1 0 0
   1 0 0
   1 0 0
   0 1 0
   0 1 0
   0 1 0
   0 0 1
   1 0 0
   0 0 1
   0 1 0
```

how i do it is using a for loop

```
for ii=1:length(ll)
   A(ii,ll(ii)=1;
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
ll=[1 1 1  2 2 2 3 1 3 2]';
A=bsxfun(@eq,ll,1:max(ll))
```

I'm using `bsxfun` to check when the entry of `ll` is equal to an element of the row vector `[1 2 3]` (in this case). If the entry of `ll` is 1, it will be equal to the entry in the first column of the `[1 2 3]` vector and will give a 1 in the first column of `A` and zeros in the rest of the columns of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to a [linear index](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html):

```
A((ll-1)*size(A,1) + (1:size(A,1)).') = 1;
```